# Problems with indexer query with Thinking Sphinx and Postgresql in productio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

I am using Rails 3.2.3, Sphinx 2.0.1 beta and Postgresql 9.1.3 in development, with this index:

```
define_index do
  indexes :name
  indexes :city

  has :id
  has :gender_cd, as :gender, type: :integer
  has "extract(year from age(birthdate))", as: :age, type: :integer
  set_property delta: true
end
```

It indexes well in dev and works, searches etc.
But when I deploy to my production server, I get the following from indexer:

```
(DSN=blah blah blah).
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.023 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
indexing index 'user_delta'...
ERROR: index 'user_delta': sql_range_query: ERROR:  column "users.birthdate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ... "users"."gender_cd" AS "gender", extract(year from age(birthdate)...
```

I thought the problem was in 8.4 pgsql, but it remains even with 9.1.4. The sphinx version is newer than in dev, 2.0.4-release.

I know this issue with GROUP BY inclusion, that's specific when using Postgres, but why it's working in dev environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL versions before 9.1 you need to `GROUP BY` all columns in the result which are not generated by an aggregate function.  In version 9.1 and later, you can omit columns which are *functionally dependent* on a column which is included in the `GROUP BY` clause. So if the issue remains on 9.1, you might be missing a primary key definition.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY

Comment: On my localhost I'm not experiencing this problem. Where is the difference?

Comment: I'm guessing they are different versions of PostgreSQL or the primary key definitions on the tables are not the same.